# Magento 2: How to solve the error " Invalid Document Element cron_expr" while try to run cron?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, crontab

I've tried to run the cron `php -f bin/magento cron:run` from the cmd prompt.
During this run, I got the following error:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
Invalid Document
Element 'cron_expr': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( schedule, config_path ).
Line: 11
```

I'm not sure what is this expecting to correct. If anyone faced the same please help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem that your `crontab.xml` has wrong `schedule` expression. We can use this site: https://crontab.guru/ to generate the cron schedule expression.

[A custom cron tut.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html)